# Neural network by using keras with python 3.6

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

As a newbie in Neural Network, I'm trying to build Neural Network in python language.

And I found that `keras` package(with backend tensorflow) is the most easiest(?) way to build Neural Network in python language.

So I built the code like below with my data by following an sample code from the website(http://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/).

```
# Create MLP in Keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy

# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(10)

# load my data 170515_data
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("170515_data.csv", delimiter="\t")

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:5]
Y = dataset[:,5]

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, input_dim=5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=80)

# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

I've followed an sample code straightforward and changed the sample code to fit in my data. **However, I did not get the results I wanted. It showed me accuracy 0.**

```
Epoch 150/150

2880/2880 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 801944.8802 - acc: 0.0000e+00     
  32/2880 [..............................] - ETA: 12s
```

I have 5 columns of inputs and 1 output in my data(the number of data: 2880 rows) like below,

```
380 17.00017    9.099979    4   744 889.7142
380 17.27766    9.099979    4   744 886.3223
380 17.49084    9.099979    4   744 884.9797
380 17.56913    9.099979    4   744 884.5085
380 17.69351    9.099979    4   744 883.8726
380 17.67508    9.099979    4   744 885.1917
380 17.64061    9.099979    4   744 887.0289
380 17.44456    9.099979    4   744 888.9369
380 17.27089    9.099979    4   744 890.7271
380 16.95173    9.099979    4   744 894.1897
380 16.43643    9.099979    4   744 898.0527
380 16.14516    9.099979    4   744 898.618
380 16.03739    9.099979    4   744 897.4402
380 16.08521    9.099979    4   744 895.0376
380 16.3003     9.099979    4   744 891.528
380 16.69974    9.099979    4   744 886.5107
380 17.14181    9.099979    4   744 882.9069
380 17.43957    9.099979    4   744 881.3522
380 17.61813    9.099979    4   744 880.3629
380 17.85716    9.179981    4   744 880.0096
380 17.91395    9.299984    4   744 881.5642
380 17.74821    9.399986    4   744 884.4379
380 17.39483    9.519989    4   744 889.0076
380 16.86244    9.639992    4   744 894.3074
380 16.18542    9.759995    4   744 898.5709
380 16          9.879997    4   744 898.3824
380 16.12275    9.879997    4   744 895.1318
380 16.47226    9.879997    4   744 890.5858
380 16.87342    9.879997    4   744 886.3694
380 17.22237    9.839996    4   744 883.8726
380 17.408      9.739994    4   744 882.4357
```

Can anybody give me a suggestion or an answer for this..?

Did I do wrong in minibatches or what should I setup more?

Please guide me on the right path.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to solve a regression problem, right? Which column is your target variable? I think the last layer's activation should be 'linear' then, not 'softmax'. Also, I think you cannot user 'accuracy' as a metric in a regression problem, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Stergios Ah ha, Thanks. yeah I was trying to solve regression problem.. not classification.. :'( Thanks for noticing! :) the last column is the target variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I see that column 1 and 4, contain the same value, so you may see if you can get more data which contain relevant information, otherwise you may be able to discard it.

This [URL](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/) is working with [Pimas Indian](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/pima+indians+diabetes) data, which is a classification problem, your data is trying to predict a number in the 800 range, hence a different approach may be required, in this case a regression predictive modeling problem. Try the following template:

```
# Vanilla Regression Model
import numpy
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
# load dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("file.csv", delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,1:4] # Discard first column...
Y = dataset[:,5]
# define base model
def baseline_model():
  # create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=4, init='normal', activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(1, init='normal'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
return model
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
# evaluate model with standardized dataset
estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, Y, cv=kfold)
print("Baseline: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :), it gives me an error with `IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1` :'(

Comment: Hm, I found out the error that it was separating as comma so I changed `delim_whitespace=True` to `sep=r','`and it gives me another error like this: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_74_input to have shape (None, 4) but got array with shape (2592, 4)`

Comment: You can reuse numpy.loadtxt code which you were already using before.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? What does kernel_initializer mean? Does it do normalization? Also, can I use cross_entropy instead of mean squared error?

Comment: Also, can I add hidden layers between `model.add(Dense..)` part? Sorry, I'm asking too many questions.. lol